# What is the meaning of the following statement regarding Zener diode addition at the output of a voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, zener, linear-regulator

What is the need for adding an external diode at the output of a series regulator? What role does it play in the application circuits shown in datasheet ?

[image]

Following is an excerpt from the datasheet of [LM723H](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Flm723)
[image]

I think the manufacturer intended the addition of a temperature compensated zener, for which the minimum voltage available is 6.2V([Ref](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snva514):)

Comment: Where does node Vz connect to?

Comment: Looks like it is just an external terminal which can be used as per the application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The datasheet has gotten a bit scrambled as companies have been bought and sold and absorbed and spun off over the past 50+ years. The note most likely should actually refer to a comment something like:

> Pulse-testing techniques must be used that will maintain the junction
> temperature as close to the ambient temperature as possible

From an old \$\mu\$A723 datasheet.

There is no relationship between the zener diode connected to Vz and the temperature coefficient in question. Usually Vz isn't even connected.

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the package options in the datasheet you referenced, the Vz pin is not brought out in the "metal" TO-100 package.

If you then look at the application circuits you will see that some of them make use of Vz.

The note is that **IF** you need Vz **AND** you are using the TO-100 package, you need to add your own outboard Zener diode to create Vz externally.

If your application does not need Vz, then you don't need an external Zener diode.

Comment: Sorry saw the details late and have edited the original question

Answer (score 4):

Only 11 pins are used in the 14-pin DIP version of LM723. The 6.2 V zener diode is accommodated in this version, with its cathode connected to Vout and its anode to Vz.

The Vz terminal is used for configuring a negative voltage regulator or a positive floating voltage regulator or a negative floating voltage regulator or a shunt regulator. https://www.mpja.com/download/lm723.pdf

The zener diode is to be connected outside the 10-pin metal package version, for lack of the 11th pin.